# $(document).ready function in thymeleaf fragment - $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, thymeleaf

I am trying to add a js file with a $(document).ready function into a thymeleaf fragment, so that the js file is always added when including the fragment. When I do this, I get the error message "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" in the browser.

pageIncludingFragment.html

```
...
<div th:include="fragment :: fragment"></div>
...
```

fragment.html

```
<div th:fragment="fragment">
   ...
   <script th:src="resources/js/fragment.js"></script>
</div>
```

fragment.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   ...
});
```

Is there a way to do this or do I have to include the script directly in pageIncludingFragment.html every time?

Comment: try `jQuery instead of $` like `jQuery(document).ready`

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Comment: Equally: have you included jQuery *before* your `<div th:fragment`?   Many frameworks/template engines include jquery at the *bottom* but your fragment script runs immediately (ie before jquery loaded if jquery is at the bottom).  Move the jquery `<script src=...jquery..` to the top or inside `<head>`

Answer (score 0):

[freedomn-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181514/freedomn-m) is right, my jquery inclusion was beneath the inclusion of the fragment.